# Как отправить int массив используя ajax в контроллер C#

Tags: c#, ajax

Подскажите как отправить массив int-ов с форма в контроллер(С#) используя ajax. 
Вот ajax запрос:

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/Main/EpidemiBuilder'
                , type: 'POST'
                , dataType: "json"

                , data: {
                    str_infected1: str_first_infected1, str_infected2: str_first_infected2, pse1: pse_1, pei1: pei_1,
                    pir1: pir_1, pim1: pim_1, pia1: pia_1, pis1: pis_1, prm1: prm_1, pam1: pam_1, par1: par_1, pas1: pas_1,
                    prs1: prs_1, pms1: pms_1, psr1: psr_1, per1: per_1, pea1: pea_1, pse2: pse_2, pei2: pei_2, pir2: pir_2,
                    pim2: pim_2, pia2: pia_2, pis2: pis_2, prm2: prm_2, pam2: pam_2, par2: par_2, pas2: pas_2, prs2: prs_2,
                    pms2: pms_2, psr2: psr_2, per2: per_2, pea2: pea_2, isTwiceModel: networkGraph.isTwoModel, isFirstStep: isFirstStepEpidemi,
                    coeff_ofreposts: coeff_reposts, was_changed_tematic: tematic_changed, selected_tematic: selected_tematic,
                    lines_micro: lines_microfractal, num_steps: save_num_steps_recurce, str_infected: str_first_infected,
                    num_nodes: save_num_nodes, isGrowth: isSetGrowth, typeNetwork: selectTypeNet, growth_rate_nodes: save_growth_nodes,
                    name_layout: save_name_layout, name_overlap: save_name_overlap, name_random: $("#name_random option:selected").val(),
                    communities: massComm
                }
                , traditional: true
                , success: function (data) {
                      if (data.success) {
                          _this.refreshEpidemiGraph(data);
                          num_nodes = data.nodeCount;
                      }                         
                }
            });
```

Массив massComm формируется из объекта.В нём number объекты лежат, проверял.

```
for (var i = 0; i < nodeId.length; i++) {
    massComm.push(communityId[nodeId[i] + '']);
}
console.log(massComm);
```

Контроллер:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ContentResult EpidemiBuilder(string str_infected1 = "", string str_infected2 = "",
            string pse1 = "", string pei1 = "", string pir1 = "", string pim1 = "", string pia1 = "",
            string pis1 = "", string prm1 = "", string pam1 = "", string par1 = "", string pas1 = "",
            string prs1 = "", string pms1 = "", string psr1 = "", string per1 = "", string pea1 = "",
            string pse2 = "", string pei2 = "", string pir2 = "", string pim2 = "", string pia2 = "",
            string pis2 = "", string prm2 = "", string pam2 = "", string par2 = "", string pas2 = "",
            string prs2 = "", string pms2 = "", string psr2 = "", string per2 = "", string pea2 = "",
            bool isTwiceModel = false, bool isFirstStep = true, int coeff_ofreposts = 10, bool was_changed_tematic = false,
            int selected_tematic = 0, int lines_micro = 1, int num_steps = 1, string str_infected = "", int id = 1, 
            int num_nodes = 20, double growth_rate_nodes=0.05, double growth_rate_edges= 0.05, bool isGrowth=false, 
            string typeNetwork = "communication", string name_layout = "FR", string name_overlap = "FSA", 
            string name_random = "AlbertBarabasi", int save = 0, List<int> list = null, long[] communities = null )
        {...}
```

Получаю 500-ую ошибку. Правда проверял на обычном массиве ([1,2,3]) все работало. В чем может быть проблема? (Сразу минусы ни кидайте я смотрел эту вопросы: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109544/how-can-i-send-int-array-from-ajax-to-c-sharp-mvc и другие но толку мало.) Что-то с массивом не так. Не понятно почему если вместо написать massComm написать [1,2,3,4], то всё передается?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

верхняя строка - это объект из которого получаю массив (вторая строка). На бэкенде все время ловлю NullReferenceException - типо ничего не передаю, хотя если написать прямо [1,2,3], то он приходит норм.

Comment: `nodeId[i] + ''`?

Comment: так к свойству объекта в js обращаются: https://learn.javascript.ru/object#доступ-через-квадратные-скобки. Массив massComm нормально формируется сейчас скрины добавлю.

Comment: Вроде разобрался что к чему, понял, что massComm пустой, так как в него не сохраняется результат предыдущего ajax запроса, хотя massComm - это глобальная переменная.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014570/save-data-from-ajax-request-in-variable-jquery - помогло